# .Net Timing Open Source Framework

Tags: asp.net, performance

I'm looking for a framework to time asp.net pages. Load times and such. I could have sworn that the makers of stackoverflow open sourced a framework for doing this. Apparently my google fu is week however as I'm not able to find it.

Comment: Are you looking for the time it takes for execution or browser load times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [MiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/).

Comment: Thats the one I was looking for.